# Coding python data to Sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, database-design

I´m trying to insert in a sqlite database a row of undefined number of events. Each event has a pair consisting on a date, and a score, lets say 9-5. As far as I know, without knowing how many columns am I going to need I cant divide each event into two columns, for instance.

So, we have a date, for example

```
datetime.today().timestamp()  
1507497496.988682
```

and a parameter, let's say

```
905
```

And in my example, we can have no less than 4 dates with each date score. I think I can´t code it all as a single real, and I heard doing it as text after lots of rows it slows down the database.

So, any ideas on how to do it?

My first aproach was adding several 0 between the date and the score, something like

```
15074974960000000905
```

but the resulting number would be far too long to fit a cell, so I´m in need of another strategy

Thanks in advance

I edit to add information. What I´m doing is an automathic process in which everyday a scraper obtains information from webs and stores it via database. So, for example, each day I have to store 10 rows. The number varies. In each row, I have to insert pairs of information like the one I posted above. The number of pairs (date in number, and score as a number) also depends on the day.

So, to sum it up, I know the format and size of the information I´m going to insert, but I dont know how many rows, nor do I know the number of events for each row.

The code would be something like this:

```
Match 1: 
Some scraping to get previous matches.
What I get (date1,score1);(date2;score2);...(daten;Score n)
```

So, When I store it in sqlite, I have a table for matches, get the id of the match I just inserted, and in another table I want to store this other data. One possible solution is to create multiple columns, but I don´t know how many will each match have. Another is to create a single data column and insert all as text, but I don´t know if after hundreds of rows that will be too heavy.

Comment: Why can't you use multiple columns? What operations do you want to do on the data that would not work?

Comment: I could use multiple columns, but this in an automathised process  and some would have 4 columns, others 16, and I think it wouldn´t be very elegant. If it is the only possible solution, I would have to go with it, but I hoped to find something different

Comment: Both multiple columns and a single text column would work. Which one works better depends on your application, about which we do not know anything.

Comment: I edited my op to add more info about what I´m doing. The thing about multiple columns is that it is variable for each row, and authomatizing it can be a pain.

Comment: Why are are multiple rows per day? What is the difference?

Comment: Each row is for a different match. Everyday there are lots of matches. If you ask why the number of columns in each row are different, then what I want is the past history. Both teams in an english soccer match will have 6 or 7 matches this season, while an irish match will have easily 20, so in the first case I would need coluns for 6, and in the second for 20.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple Xs for one Y, you should model this in the database as two tables, X and Y, with a N:1 relationship between them.

So you'd have one table for matches, and a second table `Match_History` with one row for each date/score pair (and a foreign key to the match table).

Comment: What you suggest is, get the id of the match, and in another table insert a row for each pair of data, in a way that one match generates 6 (or 20) rows? Mmm that could work